# Is seq(0, 1, length.out = 10) correct for the following output? [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

Tags: r

I'm a complete beginner and just started a data viz class. We haven't actually worked with R in class, but my prof gave us a guided exercise.

The instructions are to use the length.out argument to get the following output: `[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0`

I did:
`seq(0,1, length.out = 10)` and got
`[1] 0.0000000 0.1111111 0.2222222 0.3333333 [5] 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.6666667 0.7777778 [9] 0.8888889 1.0000000`

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong but maybe not because this isn't supposed to be a difficult exercise. The only argument that the exercise went over before this question was "by"

Thank you!

Comment: Try `seq(from=0,by=0.1, length.out = 11)`

Comment: @Duck, post as answer.

Comment: hint: `by=0.1` ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks Dr. Bolker. I have posted as answer!

Comment: @needresearchhelp By recommendation of Dr. Bolker I have posted the code as solution. If you think it was useful and helpful you could accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer or upvoting it ! It is up to you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next approach, using `by=0.1` as mentioned by @BenBolker :

```
seq(from=0,by=0.1, length.out = 11)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the starting point and the end point, You need to have 10 intervals between the starting point and the end point, that means that you need 10 + 1 = 11 numbers, thus you could do:

```
seq(0,1,length.out = 11)
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```